# Windows 10 Installed - Thinks I'm dual booting?

Tags: windows-8.1, multi-boot, windows-10

I have a laptop with 2 internal HDDs.

The 1st being my OS drive, the 2nd being a file drive.

I had Windows 8.1 installed, however I just did a format (I believe) of the OS drive and Windows 10 installed without issue.

However, now when I boot I get the following screen: Choose an operating system.

The goal was to no longer have Windows 8.1, but just have Windows 10. Any idea how this happened? At this point can I just wipe anyway reference?

[image]

Update:

This is what my Disk Management looks like... I feel like the D drive (file drive) shouldn't be set as primary? the C drive I installed on was a fresh drive. Could this be part of the problem?

[image]

Comment: Based on the screenshot.  You did not format the HDD.

Comment: That drive was a "clean" drive pulled out of the box

Comment: You indicated you only think you performed format on the system drive, the very detection of non-existent installation of Windows 8,1 indicates you didn't format the entire drive.

Comment: Hmm the D drive isn't supposed to be system, it's just a drive a drop files on... is there anyway I can make it "non-system" (remove win8 reference?)

Comment: run msconfig.exe  and delete the Windows 8.1 entry.

Answer (score 0):

Check if windows 8.1 still exists on the disk. Easiest way around this without too much hassle would be to use the "Skip the boot menu" option in EasyBCD.

Comment: How can I check if Windows 8.1 still exists? I'd prefer not to use a 3rd party solution

Comment: Or is this a command line tool I can run?

Comment: Look through your disk partitions and see if there is a C:\WINDOWS folder other than the Windows 10 one. However, if the bootloader is still located in Windows 8.1 erasing it will give you no OS found on boot hence why I suggested just skipping the menu. It's possible to move the bootloader using the bcdboot command.  EasyBCD essentially just gives a GUI for the bcdboot command and can be uninstalled after you're done with it.

Comment: My apologies, I didn't read your second comment. EasyBCD IS a third party tool that can carry out the same actions as the bcdboot command only with an easy to use GUI